# How can you save node group data to be able to be seen within unity?

Tags: node-editor, texture-baking, unity

I don't know if you just cant do it or not but I am creating a stylized texture for low poly assets for a game within unity. I am unable to get the textures working as I have used both a noise node and I have texture painted on the corners.

This is what the texture looks like

[image]

This is the node group for it
[image]

Here is the UV maps

[image]

Thank you for reading

Comment: You have to bake the texture into a new image, that will be exported to Unity.

Comment: Blender and Unity use separate shader systems - Blender nodes will not work in Unity. However, given your material looks rather simple, it may just be easier to recreate it in Unity's shader graph